# Access SqlXml returned from SQLCLR stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, xml, sqlclr

I have some C# code (SQLCLR) which is reading an XML file from the local machine into a stream and returning it to SQL as SQLXML:

### C# code

```cs
 Stream str = File.OpenRead(xmlFilePath);
 sqlXMLToReturn = new SqlXml(str);
```

### SQL CLR Call from SQL Server 2014:

```sql
DECLARE @ResultForPos xml
EXEC @ResultForPos = spGetXmlForFile
SELECT @ResultForPos
```

My breakpoints in C# code gets hit when I debug the above SQL Script from SQL Server Object explorer inside Visual Studio 2015.  There are no exceptions raised in C# code. However after running the script I get the following error in SQL Server.

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spWcfCall, Line 43
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with xml

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to do sqlXMLToReturn.Value and return a string instead of SQLXML.

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedures, whether they are pure T-SQL or SQLCLR, *always* return `INT` / `SqlInt32`. If you want to pass back `XML` / `SqlXml`, then you need to use an `OUTPUT` / `out` / `ref` parameter.

The syntax, in the end, should look similar to the following:

```
EXEC dbo.spGetXmlForFile @OutParamName = @ResultForPos OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Can I get a simple example please. When I pass in a Out parameter i still get the same error. Thank you.

Comment: @Abe If you get the same error then you are still using the `EXEC @ResultForPos = spGetXmlForFile` syntax, which can't work since stored procedures only return `INT`. I have updated my answer with the expected syntax.

Comment: @Abe Were you able to get any farther on this?